# 99% of all readings are within WHAT temperature range?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, quantile

I am a bit stumped.

"The temperature reading from a thermocouple placed in a constant-temperature medium is
normally distributed with mean of 82.5C and standard deviation .1C. 99% of all readings
are within what temperature range?"

The question states that multiple readings are taken - no sample size is given. The mean is 82.5 with standard deviation of 0.1.
I am not sure whether the question is badly phrased or some other error in it.

I attempted is as a Confidence Interval, however a N would be necessary.

I would appreciate at least a hint because I feel like I am going mad.

Comment: A confidence interval might be used if you had $n$ measurements and used their mean $\bar X$ to estimate $\mu.$ Then, using $\sigma = 0.1,$ a 99% CI for $\mu$ would be of the form $\bar X \pm 2.576\sigma/\sqrt{n}.$ But you know $\mu = 82.5,$ so you aren't being asked to find a confidence interval.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different phrasing of the same problem:

> Find an interval such that the probability that a reading lies within that interval is 99%.

Your thinking is too advanced and complicated. Do the simple and immediate thing.

Of course, there are many possible answers. Presumably you are asked to find the interval which is *centered on the mean*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate it. How can I go about finding the range without a N?  X − 2.58σ ≤ µ ≤ X + 2.58σ - would this be in the right direction?

Comment: @mariekurk I would personally put $X$ in the middle and $\mu\pm2.58\sigma$ on either side, as a matter of aesthetics. But other than that, yeah. That's the answer. And what $N$? There is no $N$. Or if you really, really insist, we're considering the limit $N\to\infty$. As in the basic elementary definition of what probability means: "For really, really large sample sizes, what ratio of samples are expected to be successes?"

Comment: thanks for this!

Comment: (+1) for suggesting symmetrical answer among many possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

simply you have to calculate which is the minimum range covering 99% of the distribution. Due to the symmetry of the Gaussian you just have to waste 0.5% per tail

Can you complete the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would this -> X − 2.58σ ≤ µ ≤ X + 2.58σ be the correct formula? And also, "have to waste 0.5% per tail" - how is that accounted for?

Comment: @mariekurk yes, exactly. for your second question observe that the area over your range is 99% that is you eliminate 0.5% in the left tail and another 0.5% in the right one

Answer (score 0):

If $X \sim \mathsf{NORM}(\mu=82.5,\sigma=0.1),$
then you seek $L$ and $U$ for which
$P(L < Y \le U) = 0.99.$ There are many solutions,
but it seems easiest to cut probability $0.005$ from
each tail of the distribution, as @tommik (+1)
has suggested.

In R, where `pnorm` is a binomial CDF and `pnorm` is
a quantile function (inverse CDF), we find
$L=82.24242, U= 82.75758.$

```
LU=qnorm(c(.005,.995), 82.5, .1); LU
[1] 82.24242 82.75758
diff(pnorm(LU, 82.5, .1))  # check
[1] 0.99

curve(dnorm(x, 82.5, .1), 82, 83, lwd= 2, ylab="PDF", 
      xlab="x", main="Central 99% of NORM(82.1, 0.1)")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=LU, lwd=2, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

*Note:* This can be done by standardizing and using printed
standard normal CDF tables, but in such tables
z-scores are usually given to only two places.

You might get better accuracy using the bottom
row of a t table (perhaps labeled 'Inf', '$\infty$'. or
'Norm'). There you can find that $2.576$ cuts
probability $0.005$ from the upper tail of a
standard normal distribution.

$$P(L < X < U) = 
P\left(\frac{L-\mu}{\sigma} < Z =\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}
<\frac{U-\mu}{\sigma}\right)=0.99,$$
where is $Z$ is a standard normal random variable, and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are known.

Set $(U-\mu)/\sigma = (U-82.5)/.1 = 2.576$ and solve for $U.$ Similarly for $L$ and $-2.576.$